# How to develop an app across multiple PCs

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control, bitbucket

I want to keep developing my android project across different computers, 
so whatever I do on pc1 should be in sync with project on pc2. I used github, but I don't like it, because it shares my project publicly and makes it accessible to anybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Bitbucket.](https://bitbucket.org/) You can have unlimited number of private repos there.

Here's a link guiding you through the process of setting up a private repo (point 4):
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-a-repository-800695642.html

Comment: what about google cloud i cant use it for that purpose

Comment: Never tried it, but yeah it seems you can use Cloud Source Repositories. Source: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/ You will be charged $1 per person if there are more than 5 people accessing the repo monthly.

Comment: so with bitbucket i ll be able to update the project in pc1 then when i open pc2 i find all the update already ?

Comment: Yes, by - in short - pushing your code to the repo on pc1 and then pulling from the repo on pc2, but since you used Github, I assume you do know how to use version control tools like Git.